# Basic Insertion Sort Algorithm on C (TDM-GCC compiler)

Tags: c, sorting, gcc, dev-c++, insertion-sort

Was learning basic sorting techniques, got stuck on Basic Insertion Sorting Algorithm I implemented myself. The code is working fine by hand, but showing incorrect output on Dev C++ using TDM-GCC compiler:

```
int B[6] = {7, 44, 6, 12, 90, 111234};
int n = sizeof(B);
int i = 0;
int val = 0;
int hole = 0;

for (i = 1; i >= n-1; i++)
{
    val = B[i];
    hole = i;

    while(hole>0 && B[hole-1]>val)
    {
        B[hole] = B[hole-1];
        hole = hole - 1;
    }
    B[hole] = val;
}

printf("The Sorted Values are:\n");

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%d ", B[i]);

return 0;
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Show us your incorrect output.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues:

```
int n = sizeof(B);
```

The size of `B` is actually the number of elements times the size of the datatype, so it's too big.  You should have this instead:

```
int n = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);
```

Also, your `for` loop condition is incorrect.  You have:

```
i >= n-1
```

Which will always be false, so the loop will never be entered.  It should be:

```
i <= n-1
```

Comment: No problem.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you feel it was useful to you.

Comment: @user5123971 Was this answer useful?